# bulk new note insert fails with too many dml statements

Tags: apex, visualforce

I trying to move notes from one object to another and reparenting them is not allowed as parentid is not a writable field. So I'm copying them. there are only 202 of them so I do not understand why this is failing. It retrieves them fine and the map is good but when the 'insert newNotes' is executed it fails with too many DML statements? This is the only DML statement

```
public void copyNotes() {     
 mev_PO_Requisition__c[] lpo = [select id,name,ao_po_id__c,copiedfromaopo__c from mev_PO_Requisition__c where copiedfromaopo__c = true];
      map<id, id> poidmap = new map<id,id>();
      set<id> lpoids = new set<id>();
      note[] newNotes = new list<note>();

      if(lpo.size()>0) {
        for(mev_PO_Requisition__c po: lpo) {
          poidmap.put(po.ao_po_id__c,po.id);
          lpoids.add(po.ao_po_id__c);
        }
        notes = [select id, parentid, title, isprivate, body, ownerid from note where parentid in :lpoids];
        if (notes.size()>0) {
          for(note n: notes) {
            id tmpid = poidmap.get(n.parentid);
            note nn = new note(parentid=tmpid,title=n.title,isprivate=n.isprivate,body=n.body,ownerid=n.ownerid);
            newNotes.add(nn);   
          }
          insert newNotes;
        }

      }      
}
```

This is the debug log and the only log generated

> 38.0
>   APEX_CODE,INFO;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;SYSTEM,INFO;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,INFO;WAVE,INFO;WORKFLOW,INFO
>   09:10:40.0 (262361)|USER_INFO|[EXTERNAL]|005d0000004XFDj|rdinardo@mevion.com.rspilot|Eastern Standard Time|GMT-05:00
>   09:10:40.0 (292848)|EXECUTION_STARTED
>   09:10:40.0 (296165)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|0661h0000008TIe|VF: /apex/rdTest4
>   09:10:40.0 (789553)|VF_DESERIALIZE_VIEWSTATE_BEGIN|0661h0000008TIe
>   09:10:40.0 (40486796)|VF_DESERIALIZE_VIEWSTATE_END
>   09:10:40.0 (41990929)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|true
>   09:10:40.0 (42133288)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|false
>   09:10:40.0 (42143400)|SYSTEM_MODE_EXIT|false
>   09:10:40.0 (65525331)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|true
>   09:10:40.0 (112082521)|SYSTEM_MODE_ENTER|false
>   09:10:40.0 (114161295)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[147]|Aggregations:0|SELECT id, name, ao_po_id__c, copiedfromaopo__c FROM mev_PO_Requisition__c WHERE copiedfromaopo__c = TRUE
>   09:10:40.0 (150955955)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[147]|Rows:1940
>   09:10:40.0 (184442969)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[157]|Aggregations:0|SELECT id, parentid, title, isprivate, body, ownerid FROM note WHERE parentid = :tmpVar1 LIMIT 100
>   09:10:40.0 (211262211)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[157]|Rows:100
>   09:10:40.0 (215766074)|DML_BEGIN|[163]|Op:Insert|Type:Note|Rows:100
>   09:10:40.0 (215849728)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[163]|System.LimitException: Too many DML statements: 1
>   09:10:40.0 (216062054)|SYSTEM_MODE_EXIT|false
>   09:10:40.0 (216155777)|FATAL_ERROR|System.LimitException: Too many DML statements: 1

Comment: Is the Visualforce page in read-only mode?

Comment: Including the fact you're working with a Visualforce Page would have been useful context from the get go.

Comment: Yes I it would've. Sorry about that. And that was the problem David. The page was showing multiple list some of them large so I made it read-only. Problem solved. Thanks to you both for your time and help

Comment: @ohmicron, please select David’s answer so that others will find it useful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Comment to Answer for posterity).

The error log is showing

> Too many DML statements: 1

because the Visualforce page is in read-only mode. (The normal DML statement limit is 150, so this is an indicator of the type of problem). Changing the Visualforce page out of read-only mode resolves this issue.